# Generalised Hadwiger conjecture for any n-dimensional body

Tags: geometry, conjectures, combinatorial-geometry

I'm speaking in reference to Hadwiger's conjecture in combinatorial geometry "Can every $n$-dimensional convex body be covered by  $2^{n}$ smaller copies of itself?"

[Image from the wikipedia page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbT6A.png)

I am aware that some upper bounds greater than $2^n$ already exist, and I was wondering whether an analogue for this problem exists that also takes concave n-dimensional bodies into account, and whether upper bounds exist for these? Or does allowing concavity cause other problems that lead to it being impossible to provide any sort of upper bound?

Kind Regards,
V

Comment: A circumference requires infinitely many smaller circumferences to cover. This is easy to see since two distinct circumferences can cross in at most two points.